# query reg hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

As we learnt hadoop is meant for batch processing of data. If we want to go for some trending based on the results produced by hadoop mapreduce jobs, what is the best way. How can we retrive mapreduce results for trending.

Is hbase can be used here. If so, is hbase is having all the capabilities of filtering and aggregate functions on the data stored in hbase?

Thanks
MRK

Comment: What do you mean by trending?

Comment: Disaply the results in graphical manner based on dynamic selection of input.

Answer (score 1):

While there is now perfect solution in hadoop word for this problem, there are a few approaches to solve this kind of problems: 
a) To produce some "on demand DataMart" using MR, load it into the RDBMS and run your queries in a real time. It can work if this data subset is much smaller then whole data set.
b) To use MPP database integrated with Hadoop. For example GreenPlum HD has MPP database pre-integrated with hadoop. 
c) To use some more light-weight MR framework : Spark. It will have much less latency, but expect your data sets to be comparable with the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/).